# error on local mysql but not on RDS mysql

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services

I have a mysql insert query which runs on aws RDS(Live env) but throws an error on my local(local env).
on local I'am using mysql V-5.6

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, 
`name`, 
`email`,
`pass`)
values('','omi','omi@gmail.com','123123')
```

id is not null and auto_increment.
The error which i get on local is 'Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1'
but when this executed on live env all the data gets inserted into table.
I cant understand what exactly is happening here. please help. thank you.
DDL of users table.
local

```
CREATE TABLE `users`
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(256) DEFAULT '',
`email` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
`pass` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25986 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Live

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(254) DEFAULT '',
`email` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
`pass` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26046 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Try NULL instead of an empty string. `values(NULL,'omi','omi@gmail.com','123123')`. Or just leave id out entirely.

Comment: Attach the *users* table ddl definition from both the local and live environment in the question.

Comment: When you have a column that is managed by the server (AUTO_INCREMENT) you do NOT specify it in your SQL statements that modify rows or columns. Just remove the reference to ID (best) or use NULL for the value (bad practice - server dependent).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error is with those quotes (''). When you want to do an insert with an auto_increment field, you have to use null as argument in the auto_increment field position. 
See if this works:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `users` 
    (`id`, `name`, `email`, `pass`)
    values(null,'omi','omi@gmail.com','123123');
```

**EDIT 1**

Using null doesn't generate any error because internally the DBMS is prepared to receive such an argument. It understands that is its duty to generate the next number of the sequence and if it hasn't any, 0 (of type integer in your case) is inserted first. I know defining "not null" in the DDL of a field and then using "null" in the DML insert statement for that exact field may look confusing, but it's just the right way to use the auto_increment feature.

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html):

> If the column is declared NOT NULL, it is also possible to assign NULL to the column to generate sequence numbers.

Also, if using an empty string as argument in an statement doesn't generate any error, it could maybe be because RDS interface has an internal function that converts empty to null. Something like the nullif function in MySQL.

Comment: Yes correct. but why this does not gives error on RDS. Instead, it inserts data.

Comment: RDS is more forgiving. What is RDS inserting? Compare the DDL for both tables. Any differences?

Comment: Good explanation. Can you add links to where you found the quoted text?

Comment: @JohnHanley, you can click on the hyperlink in the word "documentation" placed before the quoted text or use this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like that. Either dont even mention 'id' or give it null value.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (
`name`, 
`email`,
`pass`)
values('omi','omi@gmail.com','123123')
```

OR:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, 
`name`, 
`email`,
`pass`)
values('NULL','omi','omi@gmail.com','123123')
```